# R barplot call results in error: "'height' must be a vector or a matrix"

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am trying to make a bar chart for this data:

```
Area,Diversity
A,0.455
B,0.354
C,0.531
D,0.313
```

The code I've attempted is this:

```
barplot(data=pdiv, aes(x=Area, y=Diversity)) + theme_bw() + xlab("Area") + ylab("Simpson's Diversity score (1-D")
```

but it keeps coming up with this error:

```
Error in barplot.default(data = pdiv, aes(x = Area, y = Diversity)) : 
  'height' must be a vector or a matrix
```

What can I try next?

Comment: You are calling `barplot`, but you are giving arguments like it is `ggplot`.

Comment: To add what Axeman is saying, `barplot` is a base R function that does not interact with `ggplot` commands - the ggplot approach would be `ggplot(data, aes(...)) + geom_col(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

`barplot()` function requires y-axis values to be inputted directly, rather than through the `aes()` function. Try,

```r
Area <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
Diversity <- c(0.455, 0.354, 0.531, 0.313)

pdiv <- data.frame(Area, Diversity)

barplot(
  height = pdiv$Diversity, 
  names.arg = pdiv$Area, 
  xlab = "Area", 
  ylab = "Simpson's Diversity score (1-D)",
  main = "Bar Chart"
)
```

Now `height` parameter in the `barplot()` function takes the y-axis values as a vector.

Result:

[image]

Or use the equivalent `ggplot2` version:

```
ggplot(pdiv, aes(Area, Diversity)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  xlab("Area") + 
  ylab("Simpson's Diversity score (1-D)")
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer, hope you don't mind my contributions. Feel free to roll back if you don't like them.

Comment: @Axeman be my guest, good call in! ;) (I was in line with your thoughts on ggplot comment anyway)